# How to modularize a Python application

Tags: python

I've got a number of scripts that use common definitions. How do I split them in multiple files? Furthermore, the application can not be installed in any way in my scenario; it must be possible to have an arbitrary number of versions concurrently running and it must work without superuser rights. Solutions I've come up with are:

- **Duplicate code** in every
  script. Messy, and probably the worst
  scheme.
- **Put all scripts and common
  code in a single directory,** and
  use `from . import` to load them.
  The downside of this approach is that
  I'd like to put my libraries in other
  directory than the applications.
- **Put common
  code in its own directory**, write a `__init__.py` that imports all submodules and finally use `from . import` to load them.
  Keeps code organized, but it's a little bit of overhead to maintain `__init__.py` and qualify names.
- **Add the library directory to
  `sys.path` and
  `import`.** I tend to
  this, but I'm not sure whether
  fiddling with `sys.path`
  is nice code.
- **Load using
  `execfile`**
  (`exec` in Python 3).
  Combines the advantages of the
  previous two approaches: Only one
  line per module needed, and I can use
  a dedicated. On the other hand, this
  evades the python module concept and
  polutes the global namespace.
- **Write and install a module using
  `distutils`.** This
  installs the library for all python
  scripts and needs superuser rights
  and impacts other applications and is hence not applicable in my case.

What is the best method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adding to sys.path (usually using site.addsitedir) is quite common and not particularly frowned upon. Certainly you will want your common working shared stuff to be in modules somewhere convenient.

If you are using Python 2.6+ there's already a user-level modules folder you can use without having to add to sys.path or PYTHONPATH. It's ~/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages on Unix-likes - see [PEP 370](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0370/) for more information.

Comment: +1: Just set PYTHONPATH environment variable.  Simple, neat, portable, clean.  Works everywhere.

Comment: @S.Lott: Works everywhere you have a shell environment. Plus, you need a start script for this, which complicates things

Comment: @phihag: you don't actually need a start script.  PYTHONPATH can be set in your .bashrc or your Windows settings.

Answer (score 4):

You can set the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to the directory where your library files are located. This adds that path to the library search path and you can use a normal `import` to import them.

Answer (score 3):

If you have multiple environments which have various combinations of dependencies, a good solution is to use [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) to create sandboxed Python environments, each with their own set of installed packages.  Each environment will function in the same way as a system-wide Python site-packages setup, but no superuser rights are required to create local environments.

Google has [plenty of info](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en-us&q=virtualenv&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8), but [this](http://wiki.pylonshq.com/display/pylonscookbook/Using+a+Virtualenv+Sandbox) looks like a pretty good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative to manually adding the path to `sys.path` is to use the environment variable [`PYTHONPATH`](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH).

Also, [`distutils`](http://docs.python.org/install/index.html) allows you to specify a custom installation directory using

```
 python setup.py install --home=/my/dir
```

However, neither of these may be practical if you need to have multiple versions running simultaneously with the same module names. In that case you're probably best off modifying `sys.path`.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the third approach (add the directories to `sys.path`) for more than one project, and I think it's a valid approach.