# How does the layout of a Python application look?

Tags: python

In most programming environments it's clear how the code is distributed into several parts and how everything interacts. In Python I seem to be completely lost.

- How should the layout of a Python application look?

  Currently I have:

  ```
  setup.py
  application_name/
      __main__.py
      __init__.py
      views/
      controllers/
      model/
      resources/   <- images, videos, ...
  ```
- How does one execute the application?

  I've got a runner script with the following content

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/env python -m "application_name"
  ```

  Should one even use `__main__.py` for this purpose? Is a runner script necessary?
- How should one import parts of the application? (Python 2.6)

  For example in `application_name/__main__.py`

  ```
  from . import controllers.MainWindow
  ```

How do you layout your applications?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171785/how-do-you-organize-python-modules, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/527919/how-to-properly-organize-a-package-module-dependency-tree, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/501945/how-to-modularize-a-python-application

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several parts to this question so I'll try to answer them in turn:

1: Its really up to you, there are no hard-and-fast rules beyond those for establishing that a directory should be treated as a [package](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages) and so on.  Some frameworks will prescribe a directory structure using a script to generate scaffolding (a bit like Rails does in the Ruby world) but this is purely a convenience or convention of the given framework.  Organise your code and modules so they make sense logically as you would in any other language.

2: What you have there is absolutely fine.  Alternatively you can use an [installed script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874521/python-install-script-to-system) if you are using distutils, a [console_script](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools#automatic-script-creation) as part of a .egg install, or as a last resort just call the main.py (or whatever you name it) script directly.  The console_script is quite common though and is used by tools such as the [nose](http://somethingaboutorange.com/mrl/projects/nose/0.11.1/) testing framework for example.

3: There is a [PEP](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) for this specific topic.  In my experience though you should really prefer absolute imports to relative ones.  To force this behaviour you can do:

```
 from __future__ import absolute_import
```

Comment: What about explicit relative imports? `from . import subpackage`? I'm a bit concerned that absolute imports break when I move some packages around or rename them.

Comment: I hate not having clear rules for this. I'm constantly unsure if I'm doing it right. It's one of those things every programmer has to figure out alone and spends a lot of time doing exactly that. It would have saved a lot of time if there were some guidelines. (At least for me.)

Comment: gs: Python is pretty prescriptive in a lot of places, for example PEP8 which specifies the correct style to use! (C programmers HATE this...) The PEP I linked to tries to clarify the situation on imports, but as far as project layout goes thats hard to legislate.  Within a given framework yes, but otherwise its open to debate.  Best thing is to read a lot of code and see what you like.

Comment: PS: I didn't even know about `__main.py__` btw (not something I've used). Every day's a schoolday... :)

Comment: @jkp: `__main__.py` is new in Python 2.6 or 2.5. I'm using `PyQt` which doesn't force a structure. I think I'll just finish my first project in PyQt with the layout I've got and then go studying other projects. Thanks.